# Text in IF formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to develop a spreadsheet pulling data and text from another sheet within the workbook while  leaving the cell blank if not populated in the aforementioned sheet.

I am trying to develop a materials summary sheet pulling from a stock transfer sheet.

In the initial column, I have inserted the formula `=IF('Stock Issue'!D13,'Stock Issue'!D13," ")`.  This works fine in that if the cell in `Stock Issue` is populated, the quantity inserted is pulled into the new spreadsheet and if not, it is left blank.

I tried duplicating this formula in the next column for `Quantity` and the result I get is `#VALUE!`

Since this cell is populated with text (i.e., `EA`, `LF`, `SF`, etc.), is that the issue?  How can I populate with text?

Thanks

Comment: this question is not about python...

Answer (score 2):

You need to test whether the cell is blank:

```
=IF(ISBLANK('Stock Issue'!D13),"",'Stock Issue'!D13)
```

Comment: Perfect.  Worked just as envisioned.  Thanks!